# Доступ к API с нескольких источников и запись в единую базу c#

Tags: c#

Нужно получить ответ от нескольких API, сложить все в 1 базу данных. 
На данный момент получение данных происходит с одной машины(как результат получаются 100 объектов и это занимает более чем 20 сек), хотелось бы это делать параллельно с нескольких машин / сервисов. Какой подход / фреймворк для этого лучше использовать?

Comment: Используйте стандартную TPL

Comment: Андрей, дело в том, что мы сейчас и так его используем, но этого недостаточно.

Comment: Профилировщик узкое место какое показал?

Comment: Дело не в том,как быстро это выполняется у нас, а в том, как быстро мы получаем ответ от API сервиса.Учитывая то,  что мы не можем повлиять на длительность ответа, мы можем "разбросать" запросы на несколько машин и тем самым получить прирост в получении ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше в начале добавить многопоточность (для быстроты процесса), и главное сначала собрать данные и только после окончания сбора добавлять их в базу данных. 
Учитесь на чужих ошибках :D

Comment: Мы используем TPL для того, чтобы формировать запросы "быстрее". Я думал над возможностью внедрения rabbitmq или другого брокера сообщений.